# iOS 7 Critical failure: the LastResort font is unavailable

Tags: ios, fonts, ios7, uifont

When my app first launches I create a bunch of custom UIFonts (they are correctly added into the .plist). The custom fonts work perfectly until I try to create more than 9 to 10 of them. After the 9 or 10th custom font is created, I get this warning **"Critical failure: the LastResort font is unavailable.**" I only get this warning on my iOS 7 devices and I can't seem to figure out why. This has to be a bug with iOS 7 because every custom font works on my iOS 6 devices, and I'm only using 1 project. Any idea what is causing this warning, and how to fix it?

Comment: This sounds like an iOS 7 bug. But seriously, why do you need that many fonts? Just checking.

Comment: I am building a photo editing app where you can also add text to your photos. I want a wide variety of fonts for users to choose from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happened to me with iOS 7..I removed all the fonts and added carefully one by one to the plist. There was a font that was "bad" for iOS 7 and caused the mess. I hope this help)
Of course a bug in Apple's Matrix

Comment: Thanks! Removing and adding each font individually to the .plist worked. I guess since I added them in Xcode4 and then after the transition to Xcode5 there was some issues.

Comment: Was this an issue with bad font, or number of fonts?

Comment: I would say both..there is a limit of number of fonts..
I just found this problem again in my app and I will try by programatically loading the fonts and skip the plist..

Comment: please explain with a code? as i have same issue not able to resolve  Please check
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40261511/fixing-crash-critical-failure-the-lastresort-font-is-unavailable/40262158#40262158