# Crash :Critical failure: the LastResort font is unavailable in ios7

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, ios7

Iam inserting the contacts from the address book in to the sqlite3 database. for only some contacts my app is getting crashed at

```
sqlite3_finalize(statement)
```

this statement. and this is happening in ios7. The crash log is as follows

> "Critical failure: the LastResort font is unavailable. in ios"

---

```
NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into vcards (some thing data)",(something data)];
const char *insert_stmt = [insertSQL UTF8String];
      sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, insert_stmt,-1, &statement, NULL);
      if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE)
      {
         NSLog(@"Record inserted");
      }
      else {
           NSLog(@"Record inserted failed");
        }
      sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    sqlite3_close(database);
```

please any one suggest me how to fix this crash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with your contacts but to do with the fonts when transitioning from ios 6 to ios 7. Delete all the fonts in your project and then carefully add one by one to your .plist testing each time before adding the next until you find the one that is causing the problem.

Have a look at this post from someone who also had the same problem as you and the person's answer.

[Person have the same problem as you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18987027/ios-7-critical-failure-the-lastresort-font-is-unavailable)