# Fixing Crash :Critical failure: the LastResort font is unavailable

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, sqlite, core-data

I am using [this tutorial for using sqlite](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ios/ios_sqlite_database.htm) to insert 10000 entries

using this code in my `viewcontroller.m`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    [self AddTHousandsOfEntry];
}


-(void)AddTHousandsOfEntry
{
    for (int i=0; i<100500; i++) {
        NSString *regNo=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i];
        NSString *name=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"name%d",i];
        NSString *department=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"department%d",i];
        NSString *year=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"year%d",i];

        if (regNo.length>0 &&name.length>0 &&
            department.length>0 &&year.length>0 )
        {
            [[DBManager getSharedInstance]saveData:regNo name:name department: department year:year];

        }
    }
}
```

Its giving me error Crash :**Critical failure: the LastResort font is unavailable**

I am using `xcode` 5.1 with deployement target set 7.1

How to fix it.
 I got [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21007399/crash-critical-failure-the-lastresort-font-is-unavailable-in-ios7) but not seems its a genie answer>

Please help, i am unable to enter thousands of entry cause of it.
My client requirement is to use 7.1 depolyement target.

And if i set my Deployment target to 6.1 and simulator to 6.1
Then on calling AddTHousandsOfEntry dont show any error. But on clicking textfield to enter value it gives this error

**

```
Unable to load TextInput framework from /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TextInput.framework/TextInput


 No input manager class for input mode: en_US
```

**

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not issue of `10000 entries` in database but it is the issue of `font` i think. So, you can overcome it by deleting fonts from your `info.plist` and then add one by one and then test with every edition and find out which font creating issue.

Refer [this so post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21007399/crash-critical-failure-the-lastresort-font-is-unavailable-in-ios7) !!!!

Comment: how ? i not using any font? in my class or code, just use setting label and textfield with arial font using storyboard